# How to calculate the covariance due to the following transformation of variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-functions

Let $x\in \mathrm{R}$ be a random variable having univariate Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\Sigma$. Let $y$ be defined as followed:
\begin{equation}
y = f\left(x\right)\hspace{10pt};x\in\left(a,b\right)
\end{equation}
where, $f\left(x\right)$ is a function of $x$ and $(b-a) < \sqrt{\Sigma}$. In order to find the variance of $y$, I need to use the variance of $x$. I have the following question:

Since $y$ is defined for only a small subset of $x$, should I use $\Sigma$ as variance of $x$ in the calculation of variance of $y$ or should I use  $\Sigma_x$ in place of $\Sigma$, where,
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_x = \int_a^b x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-0.5\frac{x^2}{\Sigma}\right)dx
\end{equation}
Note: This is not a homework problem. This calculation is a part of a larger problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: There's no such thing as a covariance of a random variable. You can talk about the variance of x and the variance of y and the covariance of x and y...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. corrected

Comment: From the definition, it seems that $Y$ is a transformation from a truncated normal. The question later does not make much sense - in general we do expect that the distribution of $Y$ will depends on the parameter of $X$, even you change the parametrization.